# __restrict__ shared_ptr and for any class in general

Tags: c++, visual-c++, g++, clang++

Is it possible to have `__restrict__` qualifier for `std::shared_ptr`?

Suppose I have a class which wraps a pointer. Is there any mechanism to allow the end-user to add restrict qualifier to the class? This should be equivalent to giving the restrict qualifier to the wrapped pointer.

Comment: There is no `__restrict__` qualifier in C++.

Comment: Yes, hence the question is tagged with MSVC, clang and g++. I am looking for extensions which allow it. More specifically, a piece of code which works on all three compilers if possible.

Comment: I think `__restrict__` extension is only available in gcc and clang while vc has `__restrict`. And I would say that uses for these are rather restricted so it is not possible.

Answer (score 0):

IIRC, non-standard `__restrict` keyword (and its variants) applies to raw pointers (or to references in some implementation). Smart pointers are ordinary classes from the perspective of a compiler, therefore you cannot "restrict" them.

However, if you need to tell a compiler that, in some part of the code, the memory pointed to by a smart pointer is accessed exclusively via a single pointer object, you can extract a restricted raw pointer from the smart one and use it instead:

```
void f(std::shared_ptr<T>& ptr) {
  __restrict T* temp = ptr.get();
  // use temp here:
  ...
}
```